# How do I find this $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I can't seem to evaluate the $f(x)$ for this problem.

**Question**: If a function satisfies $f(x) f"(x)-f(x)f'(x)=(f'(x))^2$ such that $x\in R$ and $f(0)=f'(0)=1$, then identify which of the following statement(s) is (are) corect?

**Statements**:
$1)$Equation $f(x)=e^x$ has two solutions.

$2)$Equation $f(x)=e^x$ has exactly one solution.

$3)$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(x)-1}{x}=1$

$4)\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} f(x)=\dfrac{1}{e}$

Okay, Obviously I've observed that (3) is already correct but can't really figure out $f(x)$ for the rest.
I tried applying by parts to $$f^"(x)=\frac{f'(x)(f'(x)+f(x))}{f(x)}$$ but no fruitful result. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's solve for f(x) first.
Let $y = f(x)$. The original equation becomes:

$$ yy" -y'^2 = yy'$$
Divide both sides by y, assuming $y(x) \not= 0$:

$$ \frac{yy"-y'^2}{y^2} = \frac{y'}{y} $$
$$ \Longleftrightarrow \frac{d}{dx}\frac{y'}{y} = \frac{y'}{y}$$
$$ \Longleftrightarrow \frac{dz}{dx} = z$$

where $z = y'/y$. The general solution is $ z = Ce^x$. Applying the initial condition gives $z(0) = y'(0)/y(0) = 1 \Rightarrow C = 1$. Now solve for $y$:

$$ \frac{y'}{y} = e^x $$
$$ \Rightarrow \int \frac{y'}{y} dx = \int e^x dx$$
$$ \Rightarrow \ln y = e^x + C_1$$
$$ \Rightarrow y = C_2 \exp(e^x) $$

Applying the initial condition gives $C_2 = 1/e$, i.e.,

$$ y = f(x) = \frac{\exp(e^x)}{e}. \quad (1)$$

Now verify the following statements:

1. $f(x) = e^x$ has two solutions: wrong
2. $f(x) = e^x$ has one solution: correct

Both statements can be seen from the following:

$$ (1) \Rightarrow e^{(e^x)} = ee^x$$

Taking $\ln$ both sides gives: $e^x = 1 + x$. Solving this equation is equivalent to finding all intersections between two curves $g(x) = e^x$ and $h(x) = x+1$. Note that

- the two curves $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ have one obvious intersection at $x = 0$,
- the $h(x)$ line is tangential to $g(x)$ at the intersection $x = 0$,
- going leftwards from $x = 0$ to $-\infty$: $g(x)$ decreases more slowly than $h(x)$ because the slope $g'(x) > h'(x)$ for all $x < 0$.

Thus, we conclude that there is one and only one intersection at $x = 0$, hence $f(x) = e^x$ has only one solution.

3. $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)-1}{x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x - 0} = f'(0) = 1$: correct
4. $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = \frac{1}{e} $: correct.

Comment: @Uddeshya Singh How is it different from my solution? It is identical ; I don't mean Hoc didn't solve it, but why didn't you look for other answers before giving your own?

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite this as :

$$\frac{f(x)f''(x)-\big(f'(x)\big)^2}{\big(f(x)\big)^2}= \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

Do you see something?

> $$d\Bigg( \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\Bigg) =  \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$
>   $$\implies   \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}= e^x $$
>   This is simple linear ODE, on solving you'll get : 
>   $$f(x)= c \cdot e^{-e^x}$$
>   Using $f(0)=1$;
>   $$\boxed{f(x)= \frac{1}{e^{e^x-1}}}$$

Now you may proceed.

Comment: There is a typo in yor first equation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Where?It seems correct to me. can you edit, if something is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I misread.

Comment: how do you know that $f$ does not vanish anywhere on its domain?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  Because finally it's proved to not be, by the way, I agree I had to take a case for that.

Comment: actually the conditions of the question guarantee this in some neighborhood of $0$. And I think there should be some way to show that $f$ does not vanish anywhere, but right now not able to think of it. The solution at the end can not be used to justify the non-vanishing of $f$ because the solution itself is dependent on the non-vanishing of $f$.

Comment: BTW +1 for your efforts.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I am also trying, let me know when you succeed.Thanks  :)